# Gridview with checkbox returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, checkbox

I'm populating images from mysql database to the gridView from which the user selects images matching symptoms using checkbox. Everything works fine when the images are less than 10 but the problem comes when the gridview has more than 10 images, when the user presses the continue button It gives a null-pointer reference in Logcat

[Gridview with image from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Cih.jpg)

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.banmart.www.intergratedpestmanagement.ImageTest.CustomAdapterTwo$3.onClick(CustomAdapterTwo.java:120)
```

This is my **CustomAdapterTwo.java**

```
images = new ArrayList<>();

        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, images);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String outputStrArr;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                int count = gridView.getAdapter().getCount();

                ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) gridView.getChildAt(i);
                    checkbox = (CheckBox) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                    if(checkbox.isChecked()){
                        outputStrArr =checkbox.getTag().toString();
                        selectedItems.add(outputStrArr);

                        String [] strArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];
                        for (int j= 0; j < selectedItems.size(); j++) {
                            strArr[j] = selectedItems.get(j);
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                ResultActivity.class);

                        // Create a bundle object
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putStringArray("selectedItems", strArr);

                        // Add the bundle to the intent.
                        intent.putExtras(b);

                        // start the ResultActivity
                        startActivity(intent);

                        finish();
                        Log.d("Item "+String.valueOf(i), checkbox.getTag().toString());
                        //  Toast.makeText(CustomAdapterTwo.this,checkbox.getTag().toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//selectedItems.add(checkbox.getTag());
                    }
                }

            }

        });
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridtwo, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            viewHolder.Chkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            viewHolder.Chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    images.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.textView1, viewHolder.textView);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.imageView1, viewHolder.imageView);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox1, viewHolder.Chkbox);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ImagesLib image = images.get(position);
       viewHolder.textView.setText(image.getAltText());


        Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getImageUrl())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(viewHolder.imageView);

        viewHolder.Chkbox.setTag(image.getId());
viewHolder.Chkbox.setTag(position);
viewHolder.Chkbox.setChecked(images.get(position).isSelected());
        return convertView;
    }
```

**grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
         >
    </ImageView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**grid_gallery.xml**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#050"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Check the symptoms on the Banana Plant "
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </TableRow>


    <View
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit" >
        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>



    <View
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCheckAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Check All" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClearAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Clear All" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGetItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#070"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Continue >>" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: You can not call `gridView.getChildAt(i)` in a loop .It will give you `null` for recycled positions.  Read the docs .

Comment: This code makes me cry .... seriously? all you need to check is the data ... iterate `images`(but instance in used adapter) and check if isSelected is true ...

Answer (score 0):

Your linearlayout from this call is null

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) gridView.getChildAt(i);
```

Instead of calling the `getChildAt` you must do use this method instead

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, GridView mGridView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = mGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + mGridView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return mGridView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return mGridView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```